# Join multiple Tables including 2 join Tables

Tags: database, doctrine-orm

i try to join multiple Tables in one Query.

My Entitie Relations:

Person

```
Entities\Person:
  type: entity
  table: person
  manyToOne:
    address:
      targetEntity: Address
      joinColumn:
        name: idaddress
        referencedColumnName: idaddress
  manyToMany:
    tags:
      targetEntity: Tag
      joinTable:
        name: persons_tags
        joinColumns:
          person_idperson:
            referencedColumnName: idperson
        inverseJoinColumns:
          tag_idtag:
            referencedColumnName: idtag
```

Tag

```
Entities\Tag:
  type: entity
  table: tag
  manyToMany:
    sms:
      targetEntity: Sms
      mappedBy: tag
```

sms

```
  manyToMany:
    tag:
      targetEntity: Tag
      joinTable:
        name: sms_tags
        joinColumns:
          sms_idsms:
            referencedColumnName: idsms
        inverseJoinColumns:
          tag_idtag:
            referencedColumnName: idtag
```

This is a valid working SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.lastname, person.firstname, address.mobileprivate, address.mobilebusiness FROM
    `address`,
    `person`,
    `persons_tags`,
    `sms_tags`
WHERE
    person.idaddress = address.idaddress
    AND person.idperson = persons_tags.person_idperson
    AND persons_tags.tag_idtag = sms_tags.tag_idtag
    AND sms_tags.sms_idsms = (myINPUT)
```

Now i try to join the needed Entities in DQL to get the same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s, t, p, a 
FROM Entities\Sms s 
JOIN s.sms_idsms t 
JOIN t.person_idperson p 
JOIN p.idaddress a 
WHERE s.idsms = (myINPUT)
```

But i only get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message '
SELECT DISTINCT s, t, p, a 
FROM Entities\\Sms s 
JOIN s.sms_idsms t 
JOIN t.person_idperson p 
JOIN p.idaddress a 
WHERE s.idsms = 2' in 
/var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT DISTINCT...')
#1 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(925): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->semanticalError('Class Entities\\...')
#2 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1561): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->JoinAssociationPathExpression()
#3 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1506): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->JoinAssociationDeclaration()
#4 /var/www/ci_ in /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 49
```

How to write a DQL Query like the working SQL Query?

I try to avoid a native SQL Query

Here is a try with the Query Builder:

```
    $qb->select(array('s', 't', 'p', 'a'))
       ->from('Entities\Sms', 's')
       ->leftJoin('s.tag', 't')
       ->leftJoin('t.person', 'p')
       ->leftJoin('p.address', 'a')
       ->where('s.idsms = 1');
```

And the Error Message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message 'SELECT s, t, p, a FROM Entities\\Sms s LEFT JOIN s.tag t LEFT JOIN t.person p LEFT JOIN p.address a WHERE s.idsms = 1' in /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:39\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(429): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT s, t, p,...')\n#1 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(925): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->semanticalError('Class Entities\\...')\n#2 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1561): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->JoinAssociationPathExpression()\n#3 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1506): Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Parser->JoinAssociationDeclaration()\n#4 /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Cod in /var/www/ci_doc_rem/Codeigniter_Doctrine/source/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 49
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your entities to the question?

Comment: i've added the Entitie Relations in Question above.

at this point i am thinking of missing MEMBER OF usage?

Comment: You are joining on the columns. You shouldn't use `sms_idsms`, but `sms`. Same for `person_idperson` => `person` and `idaddress` => `address`.

Comment: still getting an error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException' with message '\nSELECT DISTINCT s, t, p, a FROM Entities\\Sms s JOIN s.sms t JOIN t.person p JOIN p.address a WHERE s.sms = 1\

Comment: can you try and remove the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: 1.  Are you opposed to query builder?
2.  Is the backside of the sms-tag written properly?

Comment: I've removed the DISTINCT, but it results in the same Error. I've added the Backside of the tag_sms relation. As i can see, it's written correctly. I've tried the Query Builder allready, but i will try again now

Comment: I've added my try with the Query Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to easy to find.

I've replaced the idname namingconvention just by 'id' for every table / entitie and had a closer look to Picking Owning and Inverse Side.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#picking-owning-and-inverse-side

This enabled me to write correct Relations.

A big Problem for me, was to decode the Debug Stack Trace to find my error.

Thanks to anyone who spend time to solve my Problem!

Comment: Could you post your solution, i.e. the query that works? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, sorry for my late Answer. I dont changed the Query. The Problem was my Annotation in the YAML Files, so that Owning and Inverse Side was not addressed correctly.

If you don't use the Standard Naming Conventions you have to Address this in your Schema, like in the Link above